# MissingServletRequestParameterException : Calling post method in Angular.js

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm trying to call a uri named `ant/talk` with post method in Angular.js.

In my code, I called using `$http.post` method in javascript with data.

```
$http.post('ant/create', {
            content : $scope.content,
            type : chatType,
            point : point
        }).then(function(response) { /* if successful request */ }
```

However, in spring controller just told me `MissingServletRequestParameterException`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ant/*")
public class AntTalkCont {
....
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String createProcess(HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale, Model model
                    , @RequestParam("content") String content) {


    String content2 = request.getParameter("content");

    logger.debug("content = {}", content);
    logger.debug("content by request = {}", content2);
....
```

But I declared `@RequestParam` in java controller above, the spring controller throwed that exception. Though I removed `RequestParam` annotation and used request.getParameter also got `null` value.

I can append content on url like this `ant/create?content='+$scope.content` but the `$scope.content` can be longer than 512 bytes so I want to use `data` object in post request.

In spring controlller, how can I fix it properly?

Here is full stacktrace

> 16:59:17.546 [http-apr-30802-exec-80] DEBUG
>   o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Error resolving argument
>   [3] [type=java.lang.String] HandlerMethod details:  Controller
>   [kr.stocktalk.webchat.cont.AntTalkCont] Method [public
>   java.lang.String
>   kr.stocktalk.webchat.cont.AntTalkCont.createProcess(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model,java.lang.String)]
>
> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
>   Required String parameter 'content' is not present    at
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:195)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:104)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
>   [spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
>   [spring-web-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>   [servlet-api.jar:na]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.3.0.RELEASE.jar:4.3.0.RELEASE]   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>   [servlet-api.jar:na]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>   [catalina.jar:8.0.24]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2503)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2492)
>   [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.24]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.24]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   [na:1.8.0_65]

Comment: The request also contains `type` and `point`. How do you access those? I have no idea why you use `@RequestParam` if you don't send any parameters.

Comment: @zeroflagL it is only prototype code, I'll add that, should I add all of request parameter to get 'content' value ?